# How to convert from evernote rich text to markdown on IPad?

Tags: ipad, html, evernote, markdown

I am using  evernote on Ipad 2 and I have notes with some formatting , e.g. links, bold/italic fonts etc.
When I try to copy and paste the content to some HTML online editor, that accepts markdown, all formatting is lost.

Can anyone suggest how to convert from evernote rich text to markdown on IPad ?

I've tried http://html2markdown.com/, but pasted text from Evernote already lost all formatting instructions.
If someone will advise, how to convert  Evernote rich text to HTML string, it will solve the problem.

An answer for a similar question [Is it possible to copy 'rich text' formatting on iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13283/is-it-possible-to-copy-rich-text-formatting-on-iphone) suggests to find an app  to see the copied text in HTML form. Can anyone suggest the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer in http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/33759-markdown-wysiwyg-support-plz/?p=191298
pointed me to 
http://markable.in/.

When logged-in (essential!) to the  http://markable.in/editor/ there is an option to import from EverNote, that will be translated to Markdown. 
Note that translation needs review, because it could have some minor bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script which may help: https://gist.github.com/pbiggar/6323088a31d689c61a24

This bulk-converts evernote files to plaintext, though it does mangle the formatting slightly, so YMMV.